# Simple way to have dynamically set readonly text boxes in gridview rows?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

My `GridView` is getting its data from a select statement that is bound to it.

I'd like to make all of the columns/rows read-only/unselectable until a user clicks the `Edit` button.

My `Edit` button is bound to `GridView1_RowEditing`

```
protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
        {            
            GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
            TextBox txtBoxResTitle = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[GridView1.EditIndex].FindControl("txtBoxResTitle");
            txtBoxResTitle.ReadOnly = false;
            txtBoxResTitle.Enabled = true;
            BindData();
        }
```

In the above snippet I am using `EditIndex` of `GridView` class to get the index of the row that was just set by the `NewEditIndex`. In the above code I also tried setting `e.NewEditIndex` to get the row to find the TextBox but the code following still doesn't seem to apply.

Essentially when I click edit I want the text boxes in the selected row for editing to become editable and when I either click `Update` or `Cancel` I plan on having the row becoming un-editable.

The above code doesn't function in either scenario (whether I use `GridView1.EditIndex or e.NewEditIndex`)

Below is my page code for the gridview.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ID="GridView1" AllowPaging="true"

          ... styling snipped ...

            OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing"
            OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating"
            OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging"
            OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit"
            OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting">

            ... styling snipped ... 

            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="pk1" Visible="false">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lblResPk1" runat="server" visible="false" Text='<%#Eval ("pk1")%>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Resource Title">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtBoxResTitle" readonly="true" Enabled="false" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval ("resource_title")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Resource Type">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtBoxResType" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval ("resource_type")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Cost">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtBoxResCost" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval ("resource_cost")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Availability">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtBoxResAvail" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval ("available")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit" ShowHeader="false">
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnUpdate" runat="server" CausesValidation="true" Text="Update" CommandName="Update"></asp:LinkButton>
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnCancel" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" Text="Cancel" CommandName="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>
</EditItemTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnEdit" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit"></asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:CommandField HeaderText="Delete" ShowDeleteButton="true" ShowHeader="true" />
<asp:CommandField HeaderText="Select" ShowSelectButton="true" ShowHeader="true" />
            </Columns>

        </asp:GridView>
            <asp:Label ID="lblDeleteException" runat="server" Text="Label" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#FF3300" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
            </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Please advise.

The bottom jquery code

```
$(function() {
$('#GridView1').find('[input type="text"]').each(function() {
     $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
}) <-------extra ) needed
  });
```

Was throwing an error about ) expected, I believe it needed one above where notated.

I added the code right inside the end tag of my update panel like such:

```
</asp:UpdatePanel>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('#GridView1').find('[input type="text"]').each(function () {
                $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            })
        });
    </script>
    </asp:Content>
```

But still the fields are editable. My Site.Master file contains the script reference to load the jquery file as I use jquery elsewhere in my project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find each textbox for a row in this event and make readonly.

```
protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Control ctrl in e.Row.Controls)
    {
        MakeTextboxesReadonly(ctrl);
    }

}

private static void MakeTextboxesReadonly(Control parent)
{
    foreach (Control ctrl in parent.Controls)
    {
        if (ctrl is TextBox)
        {
            (ctrl as TextBox).Enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In my HTML I'll need to add OnRowCreated="GridView1_RowCreated" right? How is looping through each ctrl for efficiency/page load times? Seems like it would be sub-optimal.

Comment: This preliminarily isn't working for me. Is it because I'm using a SqlDataAdapter to bind data to the gridview? The onRowCreated event is firing but when it gets to "if (ctrl is TextBox)" it doesn't accept the condition as being true.

Comment: If you are calling GridView1.DataSource = "your data source" and then calling GridView1.DataBind() then this event is firing. What is not working exactly. Can you use JQuery?

Comment: It's not working because in the instance when I debug "ctrl" is a DataControlFieldHeaderCell which will never be a TextBox.

Comment: That's why I put this comment in "You may have to check if ctrl is not a Textbox and then loop through
 it's controls if it has any, but you get the point.". Give me one sec and I'll show you how to get it.

Comment: Still not working with jquery. Check edited question.

Comment: Nevermind, ignore that, I needed to set the properties AFTER binding the data. Good work sir!

Comment: No problem. If this works for you please mark as answer.